# How I can compile $cond with $ne on mongoose aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is the sample about my data:

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId('5e982040227ddfb12bf43e39'),
  classId: 'class-1',
  state: 'active',
  logs: []
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('5e982040227ddfb12bf43e38'),
  classId: 'class-1',
  state: 'unactive',
  logs: []
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('5e982040227ddfb12bf43e40'),
  classId: 'class-1',
  state: 'graduated',
  logs: []
}]
```

I want to change state for all students in class `class-1` and state not equal unactive.

This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('student').aggregate([{
  $addFields: {
    state: {
      $cond: [{ classId: 'class-1', $ne: ['$state', 'unactive']}, 'unactive', '$state']
    },
    logs: {
      $cond: [{
        { classId: 'class-1', $ne: ['$state', 'unactive']},
        {
          $concatArrays: ['$logs', [{ from: '$state', to: 'unactive', at: new Date() }],
        '$logs'
        ]}
      }]
    }
  }
}, {
  $out: 'student'
}]);
```

But it's throw an error: `FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.`

Here is document I'm following: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

If I remove $ne condition and keep only filter by classId, It's working well, but I don't want to unactive users who guys unactived.

Here my expected resuult:

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId('5e982040227ddfb12bf43e39'),
  classId: 'class-1',
  state: 'unactive',
  logs: [{ from: 'active', to: 'unactive', at: ... }]
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('5e982040227ddfb12bf43e38'),
  classId: 'class-1',
  state: 'unactive',
  logs: []
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('5e982040227ddfb12bf43e40'),
  classId: 'class-1',
  state: 'unactive',
  logs: [{ from: 'graduated', to: 'unactive', at: ...}]
}]
```

Please give me an idea if you know the way to resolve this problem

Comment: Could you post the complete query? And what is your expected result?

Comment: Yep, I updated my question and add my expected. The active students in class-1 will be unactived, if student is unactived, keep it as current @ngShravil.py

Comment: Are you updating the `state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to update. If that's not the case then, let me know.

You are using the `$cond` operator in a wrong way. The first argument in it, expects some logical condition like `$and`, `$or`, or any combination of logical operators.

The below query will be helpful:

```js
db.student.aggregate([
  { // Unwind the 'logs' array field, along with preserving empty arrays.
    $unwind: {
      path: "$logs",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  { // Group the documents by '_id' field.
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      classId: {
        $first: "$classId"
      },
      oldState: {
        $first: "$state"
      },
      logs: { // Conditionally push the object.
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$classId",
                    "class-1"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$state",
                    "unactive"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "from": "$state",
              "to": "unactive",
              "at": "20200522"
            },
            "$$REMOVE" // If the above condition results false, then don't push.
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // Project the required fields.
    $project: {
      classId: 1,
      logs: 1,
      state: { // conditionally set the 'state' field.
        $cond: [
          {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$classId",
                  "class-1"
                ]
              },
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$oldState",
                  "unactive"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "unactive",
          "$oldState"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { // overwrite the output of this aggregation to 'student' collection.
    $out : 'student'
  }
])
```

Comment: It's availabled on mongo v4.0.4 ?

Comment: You can try and let me know.

Comment: actually, I have to push an Object into logs array. When I update state to unactive, I have to push { from: '$state', to: 'unactive', at: '20200522'  } with from is current state, to is 'unactive', and I am using $concatArrays in $cond array. I don't describe it on question because I want to focus to current issue. Let me update my question

Comment: I just updated my question, pls double check it. really sorry

Comment: I can apply a part of your command to my command, it worked but you right, aggregate have a poor performance. Should you update to filter before update, but $set or $push cannot not set value for field by value of another field right?, then $addFields and $concatArrays can do that. But $concatArrays is available in only aggregate

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/
In document, update with pipeline available on mongo v4.2 or later

Comment: Hey @VũAnhDũng, was this helpful?

Comment: Can you explain what is different between your query & my query about performance? 
But I can apply $cond: [{ $and ... }], it's made my query can run.

Comment: Oh !! $cond: [{ $and: [{ $eq: ['$classId', ...]}, { $ne: ['$state', 'uactive' ]}]}] not really working, I see all data be changed. It's not filter by classId, classId is value of ObjectId

Comment: Ah No, my mistake, classId is array of ObjectId, normal find I just find classId equal an Object. With $cond: ... I have to check classId: [ObjectId(...)]

Comment: It doesn't understand if I push String, have to parse to ObjectId :|

Comment: You can easily do it like `Objectid('yourStringID')`.

Comment: Yes, I thought it same `find` method. When I input a String to find record by Id, It still understand